# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable for locally uploaded dataset

Tags: kaggle

This code i took from kaggle from the spotify music recommendations system and uploaded the dataset locally-
`from yellowbrick.target import FeatureCorrelation

feature_names = ['acousticness', 'danceability', 'energy', 'instrumentalness',
'liveness', 'loudness', 'speechiness', 'tempo', 'valence','duration_ms','explicit','key','mode','year']

X, y = data[feature_names], data['popularity']

## Create a list of the feature names

features = np.array(feature_names)

## Instantiate the visualizer

visualizer = FeatureCorrelation(labels=features)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(20,20)
visualizer.fit(X, y)     # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()`

but i got an error and not able to run it

I got this as an error-

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
4        'liveness', 'loudness', 'speechiness', 'tempo', 'valence','duration_ms','explicit','key','mode','year']
5
----> 6 X, y = data[feature_names], data['popularity']
7
8 # Create a list of the feature names

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`